# How merge rectangles with NMBoxes?

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

I am doing a simple dectection with images. The original size of the image is 1280x1024 but I go through the 64x64 image.

If the subimage is predicted as 1 then I draw a rectangle, but when the rectangles consecutive I prefer to draw only one.

I make the selection of the rectangles with cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes, cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes return the first box no consecutie. How merge the boxes consecutive?

For example:

```py
imgDst = np.zeros((1024, 1280), dtype='float')
rect = [[448, 0, 512, 64], [512, 0, 576, 64], [576, 0, 640, 64], [576, 64, 640, 128], [128, 192, 192, 256]]

boxes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(bboxes=rects, scores=[.9, .9, .9, .9, .9], score_threshold=.5, nms_threshold=.4)
print (boxes)

rect_def = #Some merge of consecutive.
for r in rects:
     rectangle(imgDst, (r[0], r[1]), (r[2], r[3]), (0, 0, 255), 2)

Output:
[[0], [3], [4]]
```

Based on the output I consider that the rectangles 0, 1, 2 should be joined.

Comment: Please correct me if i have understood your question wrong, but if you want to join the three bboxes. You already have the coordinated of the bboxes ... get xmin, ymin, xmax, and ymax and draw the full rectangle.

Comment: Yes, but in this is a simple case. But since I know that  the rectangles 0, 1, 2 should be joined.